# Wordpress custom JSON feed with multiple categories

Tags: json, wordpress, rss, feed

Good morning to all.

It is possible to have a custom JSON feed with the last 10 posts from all categories with 10 or more posts published?

I'm doing that with a loop over all categories with 10 or more posts published using the JSON API plugin for wordpress by dphiffer

So if I have 14 categories I will do 140 requests and overload the server.

I'm searching for a way to do that with 1 or 2 requests. Like first request to get the categories indexes with 10 or more posts and the second request with all the data.

Thanks

Here is the code i've developed so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slug = 'news'; // Main categorie
    var maxLength = 10; // Total of articles per categorie
    var wpurl = 'http://wpurl.com'; // WP URL
    var loadedValue, loadedTotal;
    var categories = new Array();
    var newsData = new Array();

    //Get main categorie index by slug
    $.ajax({
        url: wpurl+'/?json=get_category_index',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            for (i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
                var cat = data.categories[i];
                if(cat.slug == slug) {
                    get_all_categories(cat.id);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
    });

    //Get all sub-categories from an categorie slug
    function get_all_categories(cat_index) {
        $.ajax({
            url: wpurl+'/?json=get_category_index&parent='+cat_index,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){
                for (i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
                    var cat = data.categories[i];
                    //Check if categorie have 10 (maxLength) or more posts. If so push it to array (categories)
                    if(cat.post_count >= maxLength) {
                        categories.push({
                            'index': cat.id,
                            'title': cat.title
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
              console.log(data);
            }
        }).done(function() {
            //Set loading
            var totalItem = categories.length*maxLength;
            var actualItem = 0;
            var loaded = 0;

            for(var i=1; i<=categories.length; i++){                    
                prepareCategory(categories[i-1].index, maxLength, i);

                function prepareCategory(categorieIndex, maxLenght, count)  {
                    var content;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: wpurl+'/api/get_category_posts?category_id='+categorieIndex+'&count='+maxLenght+'&status=publish',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(data){
                            for (e = 0; e < data.posts.length; e++) {
                                //Loading percent
                                actualItem++;
                                loaded = (actualItem/totalItem)*100;
                                document.getElementById('loadingBox').innerHTML = 'Loading: '+Math.round(loaded)+'%';
                                //Post data
                                var post = data.posts[e];
                                var title = post.title;
                                var thumb = post.thumbnail_images.appthumb.url || 'content/images/noimage.png';
                                var newContent = '<div class="new"><a href="#"><img src="'+thumb+'" width="320" height="164"><div class="new_description">'+title+'</div></a></div>';
                                var newId = 'cat'+count+'new'+(e+1);
                                newsData.push({
                                    'id': newId,
                                    'content':newContent
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                          console.log(data);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

        });
    };

    function loaded() {
        if (window.localStorage.length != 0)
        {
            localStorage.clear();
            setGlobalStorageAndRedirect();
        } else {
            setGlobalStorageAndRedirect();
        }

        function setGlobalStorageAndRedirect() {
            localStorage.setItem('postPerCat', maxLength);
            localStorage.setItem('catNumbs', categories.length);
            localStorage.setItem('wpurl', wpurl);
            localStorage.setItem('categoriesArray', JSON.stringify(categories));
            localStorage.setItem('newsData', JSON.stringify(newsData));
            window.location="main.html";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have modeled an approach. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I've added my javaScript code